# Why can't I select values in a combo box in an excel VBA form?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, combobox

I have a combo drop down box in a excel VBA form which won't let me select a value in the box which can then be uploaded into SQL.
I can see the values but I can't select one and the combo box only shows the drop down options when something is typed in.
Also the values all correspond to a certain ID number which will upload into the SQL table. When nothing is selected this uploads the value 0 into the table, however there is no zero value and I would like to prevent this from happening. If there is nothing selected I don't want anything to upload into SQL.

```
Private Sub cmb_Cause_Change()
    Dim conn As New Connection
    Dim rec As New Recordset
    Dim comm As New Command
    
    If Me.cmb_KPI.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        ' Clear the existing items in the cmb_Cause combo box
        Me.cmb_Cause.Clear
        
        ' Open the connection and set up the command
        conn.Open KPconnectionString
        Set comm.ActiveConnection = conn
        
        ' Retrieve the cause_code and cause_id values from the Cause table
        comm.CommandText = _
            "SELECT Cause_code, Cause_id " & _
            "FROM Cause " & _
            "WHERE Kpi_applicable = '" & Me.cmb_KPI & "'"
        
        rec.Open comm
        
        ' Populate the ComboBox with cause_code values
        While Not rec.EOF
            Me.cmb_Cause.AddItem rec!Cause_code
            Me.cmb_Cause.ItemData(Me.cmb_Cause.ListCount - 1) = rec!Cause_id
            rec.MoveNext
        Wend
        
        rec.Close
        conn.Close
    End If
   
    ' Select the PotentialFailure_ID value from the form
    Dim PotentialFailure_ID As Integer
    PotentialFailure_ID = Me.txt_PFID.value
    
    ' Open a new connection and set up the command
    conn.Open KPconnectionString
    Set comm.ActiveConnection = conn
    
    ' Insert the selected Cause_ID and PotentialFailure_ID into the CauseFailures table
    comm.CommandText = _
        "INSERT INTO CauseFailures (Cause_ID, PotentialFailure_ID) " & _
        "VALUES (" & Me.cmb_Cause.ItemData(Me.cmb_Cause.ListIndex) & "," & PotentialFailure_ID & ")"
    
    comm.Execute
    
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

I'm trying to create a combo drop down box in a VBA form which pulls values from a SQL table and then once a value is selected uploads that result into another table in SQL. The box is enabled.
Does anyone know why this would be or a line of code that is required to allow this to happen? ALso why will it only show options when I type a letter in?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to give help for your question as you have not posted any of your code - see 'Help others reproduce the problem' at this [SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ... in this case it would also help to know which Properties you have changed from their default values ... however, reviewing the Style, MatchEntry and MatchRequired [ComboBox Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/properties-microsoft-forms) may help you

Comment: Hi, apologies. I have uploaded the code now! Thanks for your help!